# How to prevent layer separation, when printing tall vase-like (tube) objects?

Tags: prusa-i3, abs, simplify3d

I am experiencing a minor layer separation when printing a body for a tipping-bucket rain gauge, which is basically a hollow tube with thin walls (3 mm). I am using **Prusa I3 MK2** and a **Fillamentum ABS** white plastic. The model has been sliced in **Siplify 3D** with the following settings:

- layer height: 0.2 mm
- perimeter shells: 3 layers (almost entirely
  fills up the wall)
- extruder temperature: 230 °C
- printing speed: default - 50 mm/s, outline - 35 mm/s, infill - 35 mm/s

Is it possible to prevent the irregular and layer separation by adjusting some of the settings, and not significantly increasing the printing time, which is already 13 hours?

PICTURES:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you need to use ABS, or could you try PLA, which is easier to deal with and might meet your operational environment needs?

Comment: such a large print needs a heated chamber.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be printed from ABS due to its better UV resistance. @Toonils it seems to be the problem. Thank you, I will try to create the chamber.

Comment: If the level of detail you need is not too fine, perhaps using a larger nozzle - should make for faster printing and will reduce odds of clogs/partial clogs and should improve layer adhesion (more hot plastic sticks better than less hot plastic.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing you can do for a large ABS print is to have an enclosure heated to 50C or better. For example, see [this](https://www.3dhubs.com/talk/thread/enclosed-vs-open-printers), [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/2ynb78/heated_build_enclosure_temperatures/?st=j6dk32oh&sh=2a550305), [this](http://www.shapingbits.com/3d-printing-guide/abs-3d-printing/), and other search results.

Answer (score 0):

increasing the temperature by 5 to 10° as well as, increasing the layer thickness to "0.3" or "0.35" may assist ,additionally increasing the flow rate of the filament, by a small margin at most 10%. These options should improve the quality of the print as they improve the layer adhesion, however none of these options will completely solve the problem.

alternatively you can repair the current print. In order to do this you will need to use something cot such as a soldering iron with a variable temperature, to melt and rejoined the layers. similarly you can use a 3d pen to apply additional plastic across the sections of separation in order to repair it.